# Iphone debug on device error

Tags: iphone, debugging

hi i am trying to debug my first app on device but stuck with an error below-

/Users/**edited***/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Assistant.build/Debug-iphoneos/Assistant.build/Script-D5AA2ECC1261763800B909B0.sh: line 4: /Developer/iphoneentitlements401/gen_entitlements.py: Permission denied

/Users/*edited*/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Debug-iphoneos/Assistant.app/Assistant.xcent: cannot read entitlement data

I have original developer membership!

please help!

Answer (score 0):

Check the bundle identifier in your Info.plist. Also check the code signing identity in you project and target settings (they have to be the same).

Comment: hi bundle identifier is- com.yourcompany.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}    code signing identity is selected as Any IOS- iphone developer (currently matches iphone developer ....blah blah) what is target settings? where to find them?

Comment: i am using ipod touch with latest 4.2 ios

Comment: /..../Script-D5AA2ECC1261763800B909B0.sh: line 4: /Developer/iphoneentitlements401/gen_entitlements.py: Permission denied

i have tried jail breaking and a tutorial that installs apps on iphone with dev account. would it be cfausing this issue?

Comment: You can find your target settings tappin then Project->Edit Active Target Settings. BTW make sure that the iOS version on your device is not higher then the version you are building.

Comment: yes thats where i found code signing identity and also ios deployment target is ios 4.2 and it is same as my ipod version. what about my Bundle identifier? it is com.yourcompany.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier} is this right? my app name is Assistant? and i named App ID as Assistant aswell?

Comment: my device version is 4.2.1 but in xcode there is no 4.2.1 to select, could this be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal, run the command:

```
chmod +x /Developer/iphoneentitlements401/gen_entitlements.py
```