# Error in debugging app on iphone device

Tags: iphone, debugging, jailbreak

please help with the below error i am not able to debug my app on device it says permission denied...please help!

```
PhaseScriptExecution "Run Script" build/Assistant.build/Release-iphoneos/Assistant.build/Script-D5AA2ECC1261763800B909B0.sh
cd /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant
setenv ACTION build
setenv AD_HOC_CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED NO
setenv ALTERNATE_GROUP staff
setenv ALTERNATE_MODE u+w,go-w,a+rX
setenv ALTERNATE_OWNER lharinathreddy
setenv ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS NO
setenv APPLE_INTERNAL_DEVELOPER_DIR /AppleInternal/Developer
setenv APPLE_INTERNAL_DIR /AppleInternal
setenv APPLE_INTERNAL_DOCUMENTATION_DIR /AppleInternal/Documentation
setenv APPLE_INTERNAL_LIBRARY_DIR /AppleInternal/Library
setenv APPLE_INTERNAL_TOOLS /AppleInternal/Developer/Tools
setenv APPLY_RULES_IN_COPY_FILES NO
setenv ARCHS "armv6 armv7"
setenv ARCHS_STANDARD_32_64_BIT "armv6 armv7"
setenv ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT "armv6 armv7"
setenv ARCHS_UNIVERSAL_IPHONE_OS armv7
setenv BUILD_COMPONENTS "headers build"
setenv BUILD_DIR /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build
setenv BUILD_ROOT /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build
setenv BUILD_STYLE Release
setenv BUILD_VARIANTS normal
setenv BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Release-iphoneos
setenv CACHE_ROOT /var/folders/G2/G2Pl3p1wHiKKLXgGINxCBU+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501
setenv CCHROOT /var/folders/G2/G2Pl3p1wHiKKLXgGINxCBU+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501
setenv CHMOD /bin/chmod
setenv CHOWN /usr/sbin/chown
setenv CLASS_FILE_DIR /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Assistant.build/Release-iphoneos/Assistant.build/JavaClasses
setenv CLEAN_PRECOMPS YES
setenv CLONE_HEADERS NO
setenv CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Release-iphoneos/Assistant.app
setenv CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED YES
setenv CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED YES
setenv CODE_SIGN_CONTEXT_CLASS XCiPhoneOSCodeSignContext
setenv CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS "~/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/Entitlements.plist"
setenv CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY "iPhone Developer"
setenv COMMAND_MODE legacy
setenv COMPOSITE_SDK_DIRS /var/folders/G2/G2Pl3p1wHiKKLXgGINxCBU+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/CompositeSDKs
setenv COMPRESS_PNG_FILES YES
setenv CONFIGURATION Release
setenv CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Release-iphoneos
setenv CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Assistant.build/Release-iphoneos
setenv CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH Assistant.app
setenv COPYING_PRESERVES_HFS_DATA NO
setenv COPY_PHASE_STRIP YES
setenv COPY_RESOURCES_FROM_STATIC_FRAMEWORKS YES
setenv CP /bin/cp
setenv CURRENT_ARCH armv7
setenv CURRENT_VARIANT normal
setenv DEAD_CODE_STRIPPING YES
setenv DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS YES
setenv DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT dwarf-with-dsym
setenv DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION NO
setenv DEPLOYMENT_POSTPROCESSING NO
setenv DERIVED_FILES_DIR /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Assistant.build/Release-iphoneos/Assistant.build/DerivedSources
setenv DERIVED_FILE_DIR /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Assistant.build/Release-iphoneos/Assistant.build/DerivedSources
setenv DERIVED_SOURCES_DIR /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Assistant.build/Release-iphoneos/Assistant.build/DerivedSources
setenv DEVELOPER_APPLICATIONS_DIR /Developer/Applications
setenv DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR /Developer/usr/bin
setenv DEVELOPER_DIR /Developer
setenv DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR /Developer/Library/Frameworks
setenv DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR_QUOTED "\"/Developer/Library/Frameworks\""
setenv DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR /Developer/Library
setenv DEVELOPER_SDK_DIR /Developer/SDKs
setenv DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DIR /Developer/Tools
setenv DEVELOPER_USR_DIR /Developer/usr
setenv DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE English
setenv DOCUMENTATION_FOLDER_PATH Assistant.app/English.lproj/Documentation
setenv DO_HEADER_SCANNING_IN_JAM NO
setenv DSTROOT /tmp/Assistant.dst
setenv DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME Assistant.app.dSYM
setenv DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Release-iphoneos
setenv EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME -iphoneos
setenv EMBEDDED_PROFILE_NAME embedded.mobileprovision
setenv ENABLE_HEADER_DEPENDENCIES YES
setenv ENABLE_OPENMP_SUPPORT NO
setenv ENTITLEMENTS_ALLOWED YES
setenv ENTITLEMENTS_REQUIRED YES
setenv EXCLUDED_INSTALLSRC_SUBDIRECTORY_PATTERNS ".svn .git CVS"
setenv EXCLUDED_RECURSIVE_SEARCH_PATH_SUBDIRECTORIES "*.nib *.lproj *.framework *.gch (*) CVS .svn .git *.xcodeproj *.xcode *.pbproj *.pbxproj"
setenv EXECUTABLES_FOLDER_PATH Assistant.app/Executables
setenv EXECUTABLE_FOLDER_PATH Assistant.app
setenv EXECUTABLE_NAME Assistant
setenv EXECUTABLE_PATH Assistant.app/Assistant
setenv FILE_LIST /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Assistant.build/Release-iphoneos/Assistant.build/Objects/LinkFileList
setenv FIXED_FILES_DIR /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Assistant.build/Release-iphoneos/Assistant.build/FixedFiles
setenv FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH Assistant.app/Frameworks
setenv FRAMEWORK_FLAG_PREFIX -framework
setenv FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS "\"/Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Release-iphoneos\" "
setenv FRAMEWORK_VERSION A
setenv FULL_PRODUCT_NAME Assistant.app
setenv GCC3_VERSION 3.3
setenv GCC_C_LANGUAGE_STANDARD c99
setenv GCC_INLINES_ARE_PRIVATE_EXTERN YES
setenv GCC_PFE_FILE_C_DIALECTS "c objective-c c++ objective-c++"
setenv GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER YES
setenv GCC_PREFIX_HEADER Assistant_Prefix.pch
setenv GCC_SYMBOLS_PRIVATE_EXTERN YES
setenv GCC_THUMB_SUPPORT YES
setenv GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS NO
setenv GCC_VERSION 4.2
setenv GCC_VERSION_IDENTIFIER __2
setenv GCC_WARN_ABOUT_RETURN_TYPE YES
setenv GCC_WARN_UNUSED_VARIABLE YES
setenv GENERATE_MASTER_OBJECT_FILE NO
setenv GENERATE_PKGINFO_FILE YES
setenv GENERATE_PROFILING_CODE NO
setenv GID 20
setenv GROUP staff
setenv HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_FLAT_ENTRIES_FOR_TARGET_BEING_BUILT YES
setenv HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_FRAMEWORK_ENTRIES_FOR_ALL_PRODUCT_TYPES YES
setenv HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_NONPUBLIC_NONPRIVATE_HEADERS YES
setenv HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_PROJECT_HEADERS YES
setenv HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS "\"/Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Release-iphoneos/include\" "
setenv ICONV /usr/bin/iconv
setenv INFOPLIST_EXPAND_BUILD_SETTINGS YES
setenv INFOPLIST_FILE Assistant-Info.plist
setenv INFOPLIST_OUTPUT_FORMAT binary
setenv INFOPLIST_PATH Assistant.app/Info.plist
setenv INFOPLIST_PREPROCESS NO
setenv INFOSTRINGS_PATH Assistant.app/English.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
setenv INSTALL_DIR /tmp/Assistant.dst/Users/lharinathreddy/Applications
setenv INSTALL_GROUP staff
setenv INSTALL_MODE_FLAG u+w,go-w,a+rX
setenv INSTALL_OWNER lharinathreddy
setenv INSTALL_PATH /Users/lharinathreddy/Applications
setenv INSTALL_ROOT /tmp/Assistant.dst
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.2
setenv JAVAC_DEFAULT_FLAGS "-J-Xms64m -J-XX:NewSize=4M -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF8"
setenv JAVA_APP_STUB /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Resources/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
setenv JAVA_ARCHIVE_CLASSES YES
setenv JAVA_ARCHIVE_TYPE JAR
setenv JAVA_COMPILER /usr/bin/javac
setenv JAVA_FOLDER_PATH Assistant.app/Java
setenv JAVA_FRAMEWORK_RESOURCES_DIRS Resources
setenv JAVA_JAR_FLAGS cv
setenv JAVA_SOURCE_SUBDIR .
setenv JAVA_USE_DEPENDENCIES YES
setenv JAVA_ZIP_FLAGS -urg
setenv JIKES_DEFAULT_FLAGS "+E +OLDCSO"
setenv KEEP_PRIVATE_EXTERNS NO
setenv LD_GENERATE_MAP_FILE NO
setenv LD_MAP_FILE_PATH /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Assistant.build/Release-iphoneos/Assistant.build/Assistant-LinkMap-normal-armv7.txt
setenv LD_OPENMP_FLAGS -fopenmp
setenv LEX /Developer/usr/bin/lex
setenv LIBRARY_FLAG_NOSPACE YES
setenv LIBRARY_FLAG_PREFIX -l
setenv LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS "\"/Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Release-iphoneos\" "
setenv LINKER_DISPLAYS_MANGLED_NAMES NO
setenv LINK_FILE_LIST_normal_armv6 /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Assistant.build/Release-iphoneos/Assistant.build/Objects-normal/armv6/Assistant.LinkFileList
setenv LINK_FILE_LIST_normal_armv7 /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Assistant.build/Release-iphoneos/Assistant.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Assistant.LinkFileList
setenv LINK_WITH_STANDARD_LIBRARIES YES
setenv LOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH Assistant.app/English.lproj
setenv LOCAL_ADMIN_APPS_DIR /Applications/Utilities
setenv LOCAL_APPS_DIR /Applications
setenv LOCAL_DEVELOPER_DIR /Library/Developer
setenv LOCAL_LIBRARY_DIR /Library
setenv MACH_O_TYPE mh_execute
setenv MAC_OS_X_VERSION_ACTUAL 1066
setenv MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAJOR 1060
setenv MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MINOR 0606
setenv NATIVE_ARCH i386
setenv NATIVE_ARCH_32_BIT i386
setenv NATIVE_ARCH_64_BIT x86_64
setenv NATIVE_ARCH_ACTUAL x86_64
setenv NO_COMMON YES
setenv OBJECT_FILE_DIR /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Assistant.build/Release-iphoneos/Assistant.build/Objects
setenv OBJECT_FILE_DIR_normal /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Assistant.build/Release-iphoneos/Assistant.build/Objects-normal
setenv OBJROOT /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build
setenv ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH NO
setenv OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL 0
setenv OS MACOS
setenv OSAC /usr/bin/osacompile
setenv OTHER_CFLAGS -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1
setenv OTHER_CPLUSPLUSFLAGS -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1
setenv PACKAGE_TYPE com.apple.package-type.wrapper.application
setenv PASCAL_STRINGS YES
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
setenv PATH_PREFIXES_EXCLUDED_FROM_HEADER_DEPENDENCIES "/usr/include /usr/local/include /System/Library/Frameworks /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks /Developer/Headers /Developer/SDKs /Developer/Platforms"
setenv PBDEVELOPMENTPLIST_PATH Assistant.app/pbdevelopment.plist
setenv PFE_FILE_C_DIALECTS objective-c
setenv PKGINFO_FILE_PATH /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Assistant.build/Release-iphoneos/Assistant.build/PkgInfo
setenv PKGINFO_PATH Assistant.app/PkgInfo
setenv PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_APPLICATIONS_DIR /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Applications
setenv PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin
setenv PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library
setenv PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_SDK_DIR /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs
setenv PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DIR /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Tools
setenv PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_USR_DIR /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr
setenv PLATFORM_DIR /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform
setenv PLATFORM_NAME iphoneos
setenv PLATFORM_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION 8C134
setenv PLIST_FILE_OUTPUT_FORMAT binary
setenv PLUGINS_FOLDER_PATH Assistant.app/PlugIns
setenv PREBINDING NO
setenv PRECOMPS_INCLUDE_HEADERS_FROM_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR YES
setenv PRECOMP_DESTINATION_DIR /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Assistant.build/Release-iphoneos/Assistant.build/PrefixHeaders
setenv PRESERVE_DEAD_CODE_INITS_AND_TERMS NO
setenv PRIVATE_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH Assistant.app/PrivateHeaders
setenv PRODUCT_NAME Assistant
setenv PRODUCT_SETTINGS_PATH /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/Assistant-Info.plist
setenv PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.application
setenv PROFILING_CODE NO
setenv PROJECT Assistant
setenv PROJECT_DERIVED_FILE_DIR /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Assistant.build/DerivedSources
setenv PROJECT_DIR /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant
setenv PROJECT_FILE_PATH /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/Assistant.xcodeproj
setenv PROJECT_NAME Assistant
setenv PROJECT_TEMP_DIR /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Assistant.build
setenv PROVISIONING_PROFILE_REQUIRED YES
setenv PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH Assistant.app/Headers
setenv RECURSIVE_SEARCH_PATHS_FOLLOW_SYMLINKS YES
setenv REMOVE_CVS_FROM_RESOURCES YES
setenv REMOVE_GIT_FROM_RESOURCES YES
setenv REMOVE_SVN_FROM_RESOURCES YES
setenv RESOURCE_RULES_REQUIRED YES
setenv REZ_COLLECTOR_DIR /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Assistant.build/Release-iphoneos/Assistant.build/ResourceManagerResources
setenv REZ_OBJECTS_DIR /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Assistant.build/Release-iphoneos/Assistant.build/ResourceManagerResources/Objects
setenv REZ_SEARCH_PATHS "\"/Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Release-iphoneos\" "
setenv RUN_CLANG_STATIC_ANALYZER NO
setenv SCAN_ALL_SOURCE_FILES_FOR_INCLUDES NO
setenv SCRIPTS_FOLDER_PATH Assistant.app/Scripts
setenv SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_COUNT 0
setenv SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_COUNT 0
setenv SDKROOT /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk
setenv SDK_DIR /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk
setenv SDK_NAME iphoneos4.2
setenv SED /usr/bin/sed
setenv SEPARATE_STRIP NO
setenv SEPARATE_SYMBOL_EDIT NO
setenv SET_DIR_MODE_OWNER_GROUP YES
setenv SET_FILE_MODE_OWNER_GROUP NO
setenv SHALLOW_BUNDLE YES
setenv SHARED_DERIVED_FILE_DIR /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Release-iphoneos/DerivedSources
setenv SHARED_FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH Assistant.app/SharedFrameworks
setenv SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR /var/folders/G2/G2Pl3p1wHiKKLXgGINxCBU+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders
setenv SHARED_SUPPORT_FOLDER_PATH Assistant.app/SharedSupport
setenv SKIP_INSTALL YES
setenv SOURCE_ROOT /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant
setenv SRCROOT /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant
setenv STANDARD_C_PLUS_PLUS_LIBRARY_TYPE dynamic
setenv STRINGS_FILE_OUTPUT_ENCODING binary
setenv STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT YES
setenv STRIP_STYLE all
setenv SUPPORTED_DEVICE_FAMILIES 1,2
setenv SYMBOL_REPOSITORY_DIR /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Assistant.build/Release-iphoneos/Assistant.build/SymbolRepositories
setenv SYMROOT /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build
setenv SYSTEM_ADMIN_APPS_DIR /Applications/Utilities
setenv SYSTEM_APPS_DIR /Applications
setenv SYSTEM_CORE_SERVICES_DIR /System/Library/CoreServices
setenv SYSTEM_DEMOS_DIR /Applications/Extras
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_APPS_DIR /Developer/Applications
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR /Developer/usr/bin
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DEMOS_DIR "/Developer/Applications/Utilities/Built Examples"
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DIR /Developer
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DOC_DIR "/Developer/ADC Reference Library"
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_GRAPHICS_TOOLS_DIR "/Developer/Applications/Graphics Tools"
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_JAVA_TOOLS_DIR "/Developer/Applications/Java Tools"
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_PERFORMANCE_TOOLS_DIR "/Developer/Applications/Performance Tools"
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_RELEASENOTES_DIR "/Developer/ADC Reference Library/releasenotes"
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS /Developer/Tools
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DOC_DIR "/Developer/ADC Reference Library/documentation/DeveloperTools"
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_RELEASENOTES_DIR "/Developer/ADC Reference Library/releasenotes/DeveloperTools"
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_USR_DIR /Developer/usr
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_UTILITIES_DIR /Developer/Applications/Utilities
setenv SYSTEM_DOCUMENTATION_DIR /Library/Documentation
setenv SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DIR /System/Library
setenv TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY 1
setenv TARGETNAME Assistant
setenv TARGET_BUILD_DIR /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Release-iphoneos
setenv TARGET_NAME Assistant
setenv TARGET_TEMP_DIR /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Assistant.build/Release-iphoneos/Assistant.build
setenv TEMP_DIR /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Assistant.build/Release-iphoneos/Assistant.build
setenv TEMP_FILES_DIR /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Assistant.build/Release-iphoneos/Assistant.build
setenv TEMP_FILE_DIR /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Assistant.build/Release-iphoneos/Assistant.build
setenv TEMP_ROOT /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build
setenv UID 501
setenv UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH Assistant.app
setenv UNSTRIPPED_PRODUCT NO
setenv USER lharinathreddy
setenv USER_APPS_DIR /Users/lharinathreddy/Applications
setenv USER_LIBRARY_DIR /Users/lharinathreddy/Library
setenv USE_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC YES
setenv USE_HEADERMAP YES
setenv USE_HEADER_SYMLINKS NO
setenv VALIDATE_PRODUCT YES
setenv VALID_ARCHS "armv6 armv7"
setenv VERBOSE_PBXCP NO
setenv VERSIONPLIST_PATH Assistant.app/version.plist
setenv VERSION_INFO_BUILDER lharinathreddy
setenv VERSION_INFO_FILE Assistant_vers.c
setenv VERSION_INFO_STRING "\"@(#)PROGRAM:Assistant  PROJECT:Assistant-\""
setenv WRAPPER_EXTENSION app
setenv WRAPPER_NAME Assistant.app
setenv WRAPPER_SUFFIX .app
setenv XCODE_APP_SUPPORT_DIR /Developer/Library/Xcode
setenv XCODE_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION 10M2423
setenv XCODE_VERSION_ACTUAL 0325
setenv XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR 0300
setenv XCODE_VERSION_MINOR 0320
setenv YACC /Developer/usr/bin/yacc
setenv _REAL_SDKROOT iphoneos4.0
/bin/sh -c /Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Assistant.build/Release-iphoneos/Assistant.build/Script-D5AA2ECC1261763800B909B0.sh

/Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Assistant.build/Release-iphoneos/Assistant.build/Script-D5AA2ECC1261763800B909B0.sh: line 4: /Developer/iphoneentitlements401/gen_entitlements.py: Permission denied
/Users/lharinathreddy/Desktop/XCODE/Assistant/build/Release-iphoneos/Assistant.app/Assistant.xcent: cannot read entitlement dat
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of your own question [Iphone debug on device error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839835/iphone-debug-on-device-error)

Answer (score 0):

Try quitting Xcode, deleting your build folder, restarting Xcode and rebuild.

If that doesn't fix it, try restarting your device and/or your Mac too.

Answer (score 0):

hi tried that but failed. one question it says cannot read entitlements so i digged a little and found a folder iphoneentitlements401, shouldnt this be 42 because my version is 4.2?, also my mac administrator name is diff from my developer certificate name is this ok?

thanks